# CheckBox, Multiple Items to be added over Json Writer by reading selected items from Checkbox

Tags: c#, json, checkbox

I have a Checkbox with 7 different options that can be checked and used, amonst them things like range_close and component_type_stock, component_type_lostech.

I am now trying to write them via a json writer into a json file but if I use

```
writer.WritePropertyName("ComponentTags");
writer.WriteStartObject();
writer.WritePropertyName("items"); 
writer.WriteRawValue(ComponentTagsCheckBox.CheckedItems.ToString());
```

All I get is

```
"ComponentTags": {
"items": System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox+CheckedItemCollection,
```

When I have the range_extreme and component_type_lostech checkboxes marked in the checkbox.

I already tried using a for loop by replacing the last line in the previous code snippet

```
string s = "";
for (int x = 0; x <= ComponentTagsCheckBox.CheckedItems.Count - 1; x++)
            {
s = s + ComponentTagsCheckBox.CheckedItems[x].ToString();  //+ "\n";
                               }
 writer.WriteRawValue("["+ s +"]");
```

Here the output is at least

```
"ComponentTags": {
"items": [component_type_lostechrange_extreme],
"tagSetSourceFile": ""
```

}

But the output should be this

```
"ComponentTags" : {
"items" : [
"component_type_variant",
"component_type_variant2",
  "range_extreme"
],
"tagSetSourceFile" : ""
```

I can do without it looking like the last snippet as long as the components are seperated by a semicolon and surrounded by "".

I also had an idea to split the string into an array and then seperate it again but that seems like a tad bit to much work.

Comment: Do you know what `JSON` stands for?  You could create a class of trhe desired structure and serialize it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the last line as follows:

```
writer.WriteStartArray();
foreach (var item in ComponentTagsCheckBox.CheckedItems)
{
    writer.WriteValue(item.ToString());
}

writer.WriteEnd();
```